# Any advantages on making paver stones vs laying a cement bed and cutting the joints?

Tags: patio, pavers

I have a patio area (about 50m^2) that I want a paved with "paver stones" 45x45cm made out of cement and sand. I have to make my own pavers because they don't seel pavers this size around here.

My idea is something like that:

[image]

I need to make around 250 pavers. I will be using 4 sets of forms and filling them, removing the forms, filling again, until I make about 20 pavers per day (so about 15 days of work).

The pavers would be laid on a sand bed and the joints will be 1-1.5 cm filled with sand.

This will be a lot of work. So I was thinking of an alternative, laying a concrete bed and cutting the joints with a marble saw like the one below. Can I cut the joints to be 1,5 cm wide? Are there any advantages to the paver idea (besides the easier maintenance if I need to remove some stones).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Man I hear you on the work of making the pavers but I would do it that way.  I have cut concrete and I don't think you can expect to cut with that saw and not have a lot of nicks and cutting issues, if you can cut nice straight lines.  Your pavers will look better laid out if they are perfect.  I am not sure you can duplicate that doing cuts.  Your first method seems like work but it allows you to perfect the system.  Doing it the second way seems quicker but could have worse outcomes and if you have to scrap most of the pavers it will be a mess.

Comment: For this kind of work is best to go with fine sand (best looking?) or medium (builders) sand are enough?

Answer (score 1):

Your saw cuts will **not** all be straight, so they'll look bad.
For 1 foot pavers, your talking about 400 plus feet of sawing concrete.
Not only will that generate *huge* amounts of rock dust, it'll likely wear out expensive blades/saws, and hurt your arms a **lot**.
Go with the slower cast and set method.